# Datetime comparison using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have two data.tables, I want Xdata's datetime to be greater than Ydata's StartTime and less than Ydata's EndTime.

I tried to write a practice, but it seems to lose the data.

```
library(data.table)
xdata=data.table(First=c("X1","X2","X3","X1","X3","X2"),
             Second=c("A1","A2","B3","A1","B3","C4"),
             Time=c("2018-09-01 09:21:03","2018-10-15 20:24:59","2018-10-15 12:06:46",
                "2018-10-16 18:21:11","2018-10-16 21:21:12","2018-10-17 00:00:01"))


ydata=data.table(ID=c("YY","ZZ","AA","HH"),
             StartTime=c("2018-08-21 08:00:00","2018-09-01 08:00:00",
                "2018-10-15 08:00:00","2018-10-18 08:00:00"),
             EndTime=c("2018-08-21 21:20:00","2018-09-01 21:20:00",
                     "2018-10-15 21:20:00","2018-10-18 21:20:00"))

library(dplyr)
outputXY <- xdata %>% filter(Time > ydata$StartTime & Time < ydata$EndTime)
```

This output only

```
1 X3  B3  2018-10-15 12:06:46
```

But what I need is

```
1 X1  A1  2018-09-01 09:21:03
2 X3  B3  2018-10-15 12:06:46
```

I tried to modify the code, but the result is the same

```
outputXY <- xdata[Time > ydata$StartTime & Time < ydata$EndTime]
```

How can I modify it and do what I want?

Comment: What is the link between Xdata and Ydata? it is not clear why you have that expectation. Note that you have 6 records in one table and 4 records in the other. Comparison of data.table field to a vector does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to find *all* rows in `xdata` where `Time` lies within *any* of the given intervals (`StartTime`, `EndTime`) in `ydata`.

The `inrange()` function from the [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) package was built for this purpose. As the OP has requested to use *open intervals*  (`Time > ydata$StartTime & Time < ydata$EndTime`) we need to tell `inrange()` to exclude the end points.

```
library(data.table)
# coerce to POSIXct to allow for comparison operations
xdata[, Time := as.POSIXct(Time)]
tcols <- c("StartTime", "EndTime")
ydata[, (tcols) := lapply(.SD, as.POSIXct), .SDcols = tcols]

# subsetting with open intervals
xdata[inrange(Time, ydata$StartTime, ydata$EndTime, incbounds = FALSE)]
```

> ```
>    First Second                Time
> 1:    X1     A1 2018-09-01 09:21:03
> 2:    X2     A2 2018-10-15 20:24:59
> 3:    X3     B3 2018-10-15 12:06:46
> ```

So, 3 rows of `xdata` are meeting the condition.

---

If the OP would have asked for *closed intervals* (`Time >= ydata$StartTime & Time <= ydata$EndTime`) we could have used the *inline* version of `inrange()`:

```
# subsetting with closed intervals
xdata[Time %inrange% ydata[, .(StartTime, EndTime)]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider how you want to join these two data sets. Right now my best guess is that you want all xdata times that are between ANY combination of ydata start and end times. But your code is working on vectors so it is checking whether each vector element passes the greater than and less than tests.

Let's show how the data is lining up the way you are doing it:

```
xdata$Time              ydata$StartTime        ydata$EndTime
"2018-09-01 09:21:03"   "2018-08-21 08:00:00"  "2018-08-21 21:20:00"
"2018-10-15 20:24:59"   "2018-09-01 08:00:00"  "2018-09-01 21:20:00"
"2018-10-15 12:06:46"   "2018-10-15 08:00:00"  "2018-10-15 21:20:00"
"2018-10-16 18:21:11"   "2018-10-18 08:00:00"  "2018-10-18 21:20:00"
"2018-10-16 21:21:12"   "2018-08-21 08:00:00"  "2018-08-21 21:20:00"  # recycled                     
"2018-10-17 00:00:01"   "2018-09-01 08:00:00"  "2018-09-01 21:20:00"  # recycled
```

Notice that when the data is shown to you with the vector elements side-by-side you can see that the only row where the conditions are met is for `"2018-10-15 12:06:46"   "2018-10-15 08:00:00"  "2018-10-15 21:20:00"`...

One way to do this is to use the `CJ` function to create a data.table of all combinations of Time and StartTime. Then we can create a lookup for whether or not that Time is within any of the possible time ranges.

```
# Create a table with all combinations to Time and StartTime
timecheck <- CJ(Time = xdata$Time,StartTime = ydata$StartTime)

# Join in the EndTime
timecheck <- merge(timecheck,ydata,by = "StartTime")

# Use vector math to check if the Time is between StartTime and EndTime
# for every comination of possibilities.
timecheck[,in_range := (Time > StartTime & Time < EndTime)]

# group_by Time and create a summary of whether or not that time is in
# any range
timecheck <- timecheck[,any(in_range),.(Time)]

outputXY <- xdata %>% filter(timecheck$V1)
```

This gives you an output of:

```
  First Second                Time
1    X1     A1 2018-09-01 09:21:03
2    X2     A2 2018-10-15 20:24:59
3    X3     B3 2018-10-15 12:06:46
```

I recommend that you run each step of the code and see what is being stored in each intermediary step. Also, there are other ways to do this with loops which may take less memory but don't take advantage of vector operations.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this? - assuming the same time frame for every day:

Edit: only taking into account dates existing in `ydata`

```
library(data.table)

xdata=data.table(First=c("X1","X2","X3","X1","X3","X2"),
                 Second=c("A1","A2","B3","A1","B3","C4"),
                 Time=c("2018-09-01 09:21:03","2018-10-15 20:24:59","2018-10-15 12:06:46",
                        "2018-10-16 18:21:11","2018-10-16 21:21:12","2018-10-17 00:00:01"))

ydata=data.table(ID=c("YY","ZZ","AA","HH"),
                 StartTime=c("2018-08-21 08:00:00","2018-09-01 08:00:00",
                             "2018-10-15 08:00:00","2018-10-18 08:00:00"),
                 EndTime=c("2018-08-21 21:20:00","2018-09-01 21:20:00",
                           "2018-10-15 21:20:00","2018-10-18 21:20:00"))

xdata[, Date := as.Date(Time)]
ydata[, Date := as.Date(StartTime)]
xdata <- xdata[ydata, on = "Date", nomatch = 0]
outputXY <- xdata[Time > StartTime & Time < EndTime]
outputXY[, c("Date", "StartTime", "EndTime", "ID") := NULL]

print(outputXY)
```

---

But then the result would be:

```
   First Second                Time
1:    X1     A1 2018-09-01 09:21:03
2:    X2     A2 2018-10-15 20:24:59
3:    X3     B3 2018-10-15 12:06:46
```

Comment: You're just creating new StartTime and EndTime values that weren't in the original data?

Comment: As mentioned in the answer that was based on assumption. Added another filter now.